# Inserting Array Formula with VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, worksheet-function

I am trying to insert an array formula using VBA but I keep getting the error

**"Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class"**

```
Sub Insert()

Range("J2").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$B:$B, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")"

End Sub
```

I know about the 255 maximum character count so I shortened the formula to the below and I get the same error.

```
Sub Insert()

Range("J2").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C, SMALL(IF(A2='C:\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$B:$B, ROW('C:\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C)-MIN(ROW('C:\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")"

End Sub
```

Does anybody know where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try changing of:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$B:$B, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")"
```

with:

```
Range("J2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$B:$B, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C))+1, """"), ROW(A1))),"""")"
```

It is only a matter of doubling the double quotes when write the formula from VBA and no `Selection` is necessary...